# Best python way to remove/filter/decode these characters from the .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, character-encoding, teradata

I am getting this data from a DB table and the encoding does not seem to be working.

- Ã©
- Ã© Ã©
- Ãš Ã© Ã© Ã©Ã©
- Ã® Ã©Ã©
- Ã©
- Ã§ Ã©

I tried changing the encoding of the file in Sublime but that wouldn't work. I also tried a few encode/decode combinations I found here but nothing is resolving it.

I am using Teradata.

Any idea how to figure out what the encoding is and how to set it to something readable?
Preferably in Latin alphabet.

Comment: Which driver are you using to connect to Teradata? Teradata SQL Driver for Python (`teradatasql`)? It may also depend on how the data was loaded. Maybe use the Teradata `CHAR2HEXINT` function to help figure out what data is actually stored, as a first step.

Comment: Is the data coming this way from a Teradata table?  If So, what is the character set for the table?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should tell to MySQL that the connection must be made in UTF-8.
You can check this 2 answers:
[first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861358/strange-characters-in-database-text-%C3%83-%C3%83-%C2%A2-%C3%A2-%E2%82%AC)
[second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881911/problem-with-special-characters/3882072#3882072)

Comment: I am using Teradata. Edited the question. Any idea how to do it there?